# Remove Twenty Twelve themes responsiveness in Internet Explorer

Tags: customization

I've researched everywhere and I cannot find anything about my issue with Twenty Twelve theme:

Is there a way to disable the responsive feature **ONLY** for IE and leave it active for the rest of the browsers? (it works perfectly in modern browsers).
I mean, it doesn't matter if IE shows always a fixed version of the site, in fact it's what I want if the visitor is using any version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of TwentyTwelve.
2. Copy the header.php to your child theme directory. Modify it to add conditional comments to load an "Internet Exlorer" only version of you stylesheet.

Use TwentyTwelve's style.css as a starting point to create your IE only CSS file, or just override the responsive bits that you don't like.

Comment: thanks by the answer but that doesnt solve the issue, i have already point 1 and 2 of your list and width fixed in the stylesheet of ie but somehow its still resizing images.